# Laravel Relationships (With)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am fairly new to Laravel.

I am attempting to extract data from my database using Laravel's Eloquent query builder, I can extract all data without a problem, however I want to add a constraint to the second table in the relationship which SHOULD result in no data returning at all if its not true.

However when I try this, I doesn't return the second tables data but still returns the initial tables data, causing havoc in my view.

This is what I have:

```
$accounts = Account::with(array('booking' => function($query)
{
     $query->where('status', '=', 'booked');
}))
->get();
```

I am making sure to setup the relationship in the model, however for some reason I get a response like this:

```
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    ["booking_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["account_paid"]=>
    int(1)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-22 11:10:49"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-22 11:10:49"
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    ["booking_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["account_paid"]=>
    int(1)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-22 11:10:49"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-22 11:10:49"
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["booking"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

With booking set to null, however what I want is for nothing to return at all if the condition is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$accounts = Account::with('booking')
    ->whereHas(['booking' => function($q)
    {
        $q->where('status', 'booked');
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I was looking for! thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$accounts = Account::with(array('booking' => function($query)
     {
          $query->where('status', '=', 'booked');
      }))
     ->whereHas(array('booking' => function($query)
     {
          $query->where('status', '=', 'booked');
      }))
    ->get();
```

This is the alternative way.

Comment: This was almost perfect! I actually used it to figure out Alexey Mazenin's solution just before seeing his post :D Thanks for your help :)